# Monads and Decorator pattern

Tags: java, clojure, monads

I'm new to functional programming. While following a tutorial on Monads, I got to think it as the analogy of Decorator pattern in OOP. Am I correct or is there any design pattern that closely resembles Monads ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Monads are definitely not decorators. There isn't a standard OOP pattern in common use that is a direct analogy of monads. Though you can implement monads in OOP just fine, see e.g.:

- http://logicaltypes.blogspot.sg/2011/09/monads-in-java.html

The best Clojure-based monad tutorial I know of is this video series by Brian Marick:

- https://vimeo.com/20717301

I suggest watching this through - it's a pretty good introduction with lots of examples.

Comment: I think, monads (in functional programming) are the pure-functional way of modeling lacking but convienent impure semantics found in "OOP". Monads are like a Turing Machine description using lambda expressions. There is no OOP pattern because OOP doesn't need it. Monadic effects are already implanted in semantics of OOP languages. That's why core functional programmers have difficulties explaining their meaning to outsiders in an easy way because it's further away from their core paradigm. Maybe, a mathematical description of programming semantics is even a monad in FP sense itself.

Comment: You asserted that they aren't but you neither described what they were or how they were different.

Comment: I think it's more correct to say that they're not *just* decorators. They surely can be described as decorators (i.e. wrapping of a value in order to add behavior to the value), but with some strict rules to make them chainable.

Answer (score 2):

you can start thinking about monads as about "overridable semicolons", due to the known syntax-sugar in Haskell

in general, that does mean you can have same control structure (code block) doing different things depending on which monad is currently used

qick example in Haskell

```
import Data.Maybe
import Data.List


funcMaybe x = do
  z <- x
  return $ z * z

funcList x = do
  z <- x
  return $ z * z

runMaybe = funcMaybe ( Just 5 )

runList = funcList [ 5, 6 ]
```

being executed in GHCI, it will prompt

```
ghci> runMaybe 
Just 25
ghci> runList 
[25, 36]
```

as you can see, the same code block produces different results - List in one case and Maybe in another case, wrapped into appropriate data structure

Answer (score -2):

Monads are like a `function composition on steroids` and there is no similar powerful concept in OO world.

Comment: This doesn't tell much. I don't know what "functional composition on steroids" means. This mainly states that monads aren't like "decorator" pattern, because it's from the OO world. P.S. I don't understand monads, so I don't know how to answer the question.

Comment: As ivant says this does not tell me anything about Monads for someone new to them.

Comment: The question is about comparing monads to any similar design pattern in OO world. Doesn't that mean the person knows about monads and then only you can compare it to other things? This question is not about explaining moands, if you want to learn moands then please go through various tutorials available. I think you guys didn't get moands and saw an opportunity in this question as it tries to compare moands to OO, sorry to disappoint you but you cannot learn moands by comparing it to any OO concept.

Comment: @ankur [good OO introduction to monads](https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/83/super-quick-intro-to-monads)